# Javascript window.opener not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.opener

I've developed a plugin that open a pop up. Inside this pop up i have a link that clos my pop up and redirect the url of the parent, like this :

```
window.parent.opener.location = "http://google.fr"; 
or   
window.opener.location =     "http://google.fr";
```

Both are working but in some versions of IE, they don't. My parent page isn't on the same domain of my children page, but even when it is the case, it still doesn't work.
IE puts a message at the bottom asking  if I want to let the website do this.
I'd like to know if there is a way to force IE to do it by default, without decreasing the security.
Thanks.

Comment: Which one you've written first ? `closer` or `opener` code?

Comment: I change the parent opener location and after I close the popup, It works well in all browsers, and if I decrease the default security level on IE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window.opener` won't work in IE under default security level if the child window is from a different domain..

An option is to use `location.href` to redirect the child window to a page in the domain same as the parent window and then use `window.opener`

Comment: if both parent and child having the same domain, then the window.opener will work in IE?