# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference in IE 10
my js code is as follows

```
if(contractStatus != null || contractStatus!='')
{
            window.opener.document.getElementById('contractStatus').value=contractStatus;
}
```

This works fine in other browsers like FF,chrome but in IE gives the error.Any ideas as how o make this work in IE

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364576/javascript-window-opener-not-working-in-ie-10

Comment: @NimrodArgov:-No its not a duplicate,as i cannot alter the security levels in IE and still want to be able to access elements of parent window.

Comment: Remove the java and JSP tags, this has nothing to do with Java at all.